# How to close a window when you click a button to open another window

Tags: button, python-3.x, tkinter, window

I am working on a program that will allow someone to enter details in order to write a CV. I am using the Tkinter module (as extra practice) but am already stuck on the menu!

At the moment I have three different options the user can choose: Write CV, Review CV and Exit. I have created a button for each option and when the user presses the button it'll open, however the menu window remains open (there is a different subroutine for each option).

I understand that you need to do something like `window.destroy()`, however I'm not sure how to give a button two commands without doing something too fiddly like create more subroutines etc.?

The other option I think I'd prefer is is I could clear the menu screen?

Here is the programming I have at the moment:

```
def Main_Menu():
    import tkinter
    main_menu = tkinter.Tk()
    main_menu.title("CV Writer")
    main_menu.geometry("300x300")
    main_menu.wm_iconbitmap('cv_icon.ico')
    title = tkinter.Label(main_menu, text = "Main Menu", font=("Helvetica",25))
    title.pack()
    gap = tkinter.Label(main_menu, text = "")
    gap.pack()
    write_cv = tkinter.Button(main_menu, text = "1) Write CV", font=("Helvetica"), command=Write_CV)
    write_cv.pack()
    review_cv = tkinter.Button(main_menu, text = "2) Review CV", font=("Helvetica"), command=Review_CV)
    review_cv.pack()
    leave = tkinter.Button(main_menu, text = "3) Exit", font=("Helvetica"), command=Exit)
    leave.pack()
    main_menu.mainloop()

def Write_CV():
    import tkinter
    write_cv = tkinter.Tk()
    write_cv.geometry("300x300")
    write_cv.title("Write CV")

def Review_CV():
    import tkinter
    review_cv = tkinter.Tk()
    review_cv.geometry("300x300")
    review_cv.title("Review CV")

def Exit():
    import tkinter
    leave = tkinter.Tk()
    leave.geometry("300x300")
    leave.title("Exit")

Main_Menu()
```

Running the program should help make this question make more sense!

I am so sorry for the wordy question, but any kind of help would be appreciated! Please bear in mind I am only a GCSE student so simple language would also be so nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you importing `tkinter` under each method, it's completely useless. Simply import it once at the beginning of your file with a syntax like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

So that you can refer to the widgets simply with the duo `tk`:

```
btn = tk.Button(None, text='I can simply refer to a widget with tk')
```

Apart from this, the structure of your program is really bad. In my opinion, you should not instantiate `Tk` inside your function `Main_Menu`, because it will only be visible inside it. If you want to refer to the master or root or whatever you want to call the instance of `Tk`, you can't, because it's a local instance, as I said above.

I usually instantiate `Tk` in the main function of my program, or in the following [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)  construct:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    master = tk.Tk()  # note I am using "tk"
    # create your objects or call your functions here
    master.mainloop()
```

Your are creating an instance of `Tk`in each of your function, that is really a bad practice, never do that. You should only create one instance of `Tk` for each Tkinter application.

You should use the object-oriented paradigm or make all your widgets global to structure your application.

Except these details, you can simply call `master.destroy()` when you want to destroy your main window and all its children widgets, where master is the `Tk` instance.

In general, you have a lot of errors and bad practices. My advice is:

> Read a tutorial on Python first and then on Tkinter, before
>   proceeding.

Comment: Umm, ok. So I searched around and found a good website, and I can see a lot that I've done wrong. Thank you for pointing this out that I can improve my programming!